# Connect three android to one arduino mega

Tags: serial, arduino-mega

Android Arduino Mega SerialPort1 SerialPort2 SerialPort3

Is it possible to connect three Android tablets to the Arduino mega through three SerialPort? Rx1 Tx1; Rx2 Tx2; Rx3 Tx3

I managed to connect only one device directly through the cable, but this is only one device.

Comment: Sure. Three USB to UART adaptors. Or three serial Bluetooth modules.

Comment: may have information how to do this? Link?

Comment: If using USB to UART: plug one end into the phone. Plug the other end into the TX/RX pins. Profit. If using bluetooth it's identical to using just one module.

Comment: Not every library supports USB-UART, I have already tried five USB-UARTs in the application, there is very little information on the Internet about connecting USB-UART to Android applications.

Comment: Then you need to find one that *does* work.

Comment: where is the problem, if you connected one?

Comment: @Juraj I guess he connected the Arduino directly through it's built in USB port.

Comment: then it is about USB chip drivers for Android?

Comment: https://github.com/felHR85/UsbSerial 
I found the library, I think I will understand, thanks